# Unity bowling pins detection

Tags: unity, unityscript

I'am working on bowling ball game and I want to detect how many bowling pins has been knocked down by ball? **What is the solution for this problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on precise requirements, the detection can be as simple as checking the `transform.position.y`:

1. (optional) add child `Top` at top of each bowling pin
2. When placed, record the vertical position of (`Top` of) pin
3. each `Update()` check if pin's original and current vertical position difference is greater than a threshold (e.g. 1/2 pin height)

   `bool isKnocked = Mathf.Abs(transform.position.y - originalY) > halfHeightThreshold;`
4. (optional) when crossed the threshold, emit `PinKnocked`, a custom `UnityEvent<Pin>` which you have subscribed to in your game logic controller (e.g. `GameManager`)

   `if(isKnocked && !wasKnockedLastFrame) OnKnocked?.Invoke(this);`

Comment: could you explain the 3rd step

Comment: I was using z for difference but as you guys suggested to use y axis for get the difference b/w current and original, it is working fine but still I didn't understand why and how y axis working in this problem.

Comment: @AbhinaySInghNegi it all depends on what is you `up` axis it can be either of the x,y,z or arbitrary combination of those. The default one for Unity is `y`, so I guess it would make more sense to include it in the answer.

Comment: hey thanks for updating your answers now it became more clear for me.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example similar to how I detected domino tipping in [Last One Standing](https://youtu.be/7_nVCkj-oGg).

```
public class Tippable : MonoBehaviour {

    // roughly 1/sqrt(2), for a 45 degree angle.
    const float TIP_THRESHOLD = 0.707f;

    // This lets you register another script to
    // listen for "tip" events & tally them.
    public UnityEvent onTip;

    public bool tipped {get; private set}

    // Start with a loop to check if we're tipped over.
    IEnumerator Start() {

        while(!tipped) {
            // Wait till next frame.
            yield return null;

            // Check if our local up is not very upward anymore.
            tipped = transform.up.y < TIP_THRESHOLD;
        }

        // Report that we've tipped.
        onTip.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answers it also helped me, I have to change my code slightly. And your **Last One Standing.** is very nice game.